# Accessing AWS SQS running under different AWS root account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

**Background:**
My application reads from a AWS SQS queue. I have all my AWS Resources under one AWS account [not IAM user accounts but main AWS root account].

**Question:**
I have to access the SQS queue which is created under an AWS account that is different from account for all my AWS resources. My question is will this work. 
I only have one account to experiment with and cannot test the scenario my self.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, permission can be granted to allow a different AWS account to push messages to your SQS queues.

See: [Amazon SQS Policy Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/SQSExamples.html)

It is simple to create another AWS account if you wish to test this process. You can even link your accounts via [Consolidated Billing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/consolidated-billing.html). There is no charge for an additional account.

Comment: Thanks John. I was able to use SQS across accounts with policy changes.

Comment: Do we need the credentials of the account (with SQS) to send msg from SQS client?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-creating-custom-policies-access-policy-examples.html

You just specify correct policy!

For example:

```
{   
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "UseCase2",
   "Statement" : [{
      "Sid": "1", 
      "Effect": "Allow",           
      "Principal": {
         "AWS": [
            "111122223333",
            "444455556666"
         ]
      },
      "Action": [
         "sqs:SendMessage",
         "sqs:ReceiveMessage"
      ], 
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:444455556666:queue2",
      "Condition": {
         "DateLessThan": {
            "AWS:CurrentTime": "2009-06-30T12:00Z"
         }
      }   
   }]
}
```

Enjoy!